# Getting too many deadlock errors while updating MSSQL table with pyodbc in parallel with multiprocessing

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, pyodbc, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to open pickle files that have data within them, then update a MSSQL table with that data. It was taking forever, 10 days to update 1,000,000 rows. So i wrote a script for more parallelism. The more processes i run it with the more errors i get like this

```
(<class 'pyodbc.Error'>, Error('40001', '[40001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Dri
ver][SQL Server]Transaction (Process ID 93) was deadlocked on lock resources wit
h another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transact
ion. (1205) (SQLExecDirectW)'), <traceback object at 0x0000000002791808>)
```

As you can see in my code i keep trying to process the update until successful and even sleep for a second here

```
while True:
    try:
        updated = cursor.execute(update,'Yes', fileName+'.'+ext, dt, size,uniqueID )
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
        print sys.exc_info()
```

Is this because when you use the multiprocessing module in windows it uses os.spawn instead of os.fork ?

Is there a way to do this that will provide more speed up?

I was told that the table can handle way more transactions then this...

```
#!C:/Python/python.exe -u

import pyodbc,re,pickle,os,glob,sys,time
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process, Queue, current_process


def UpDater(pickleQueue):

   for pi in iter(pickleQueue.get, 'STOP'):
        name = current_process().name
        f=pi

        cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=database.windows.net;DATABASE=DB;UID=user;PWD=pwd');
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        update = ("""UPDATE DocumentList
                SET Downloaded=?, DownLoadedAs=?,DownLoadedWhen=?,DownLoadedSizeKB=?
                WHERE DocNumberSequence=?""")

        r = re.compile('\d+')

        pkl_file = open(pi, 'rb')
        meta = pickle.load(pkl_file)
        fileName = meta[0][0]
        pl = r.findall(fileName)
        l= int(len(pl)-1)
        ext = meta[0][1]
        url = meta[0][2]
        uniqueID = pl[l]
        dt = meta[0][4]
        size = meta[0][5]

        while True:
            try:
                updated = cursor.execute(update,'Yes', fileName+'.'+ext, dt, size,uniqueID )
                break
            except:
                time.sleep(1)
                print sys.exc_info() 

        print uniqueID  

        cnxn.commit()
        pkl_file.close()
        os.remove(fileName+'.pkl')
        cnxn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    os.chdir('Pickles')
    pickles = glob.glob("*.pkl")
    pickleQueue=Queue();processes =[];

    for item in pickles:
        pickleQueue.put(item)


    workers = int(sys.argv[1]);
    for x in xrange(workers):
            p = Process(target=UpDater,args=(pickleQueue,))
            p.start()
            processes.append(p)
            pickleQueue.put('STOP')

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

I am using Windows 7 and python 2.7 Anaconda Distribution

*EDIT*
The answer below to use row locks stopped the error from happening. However, the updates were still slow. Turns out an old fashion index on the primary key was needed for 100x speed up

Comment: I don't know what causes deadlocks, but you can try to connect to database once in the beginning of `UpDater` (before `for pi` loop) and run queries using the same connection. It should make the function faster. `r` could also be compiled before loop since you use the same regex in every iteration.

Comment: No i already ran into that problem. You can not share one connection among multipe processes. You can only pass objects that are "picklable" and db connections are not one of them.

Comment: Ok that gave me a huge list of errors saying connection closed...

Comment: Ah, now I see what's done there (sorry, haven't read it thoroughly at the beginning). Do you use a process for each file update? Can you try to use one process for a chunk of updates? I don't know python well but the thing I want to say is that connecting to database is rather heavy (authentication etc) so connecting and disconnecting for each query may affect performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to try. Using sleeps is a bad idea. First, could you try row level locking?

```
    update = ("""UPDATE DocumentList WITH (ROWLOCK)
            SET Downloaded=?, DownLoadedAs=?,DownLoadedWhen=?,DownLoadedSizeKB=?
            WHERE DocNumberSequence=? """)
```

Another option would be to wrap each in a transaction:

```
    update = ("""
        BEGIN TRANSACTION my_trans;
            UPDATE DocumentList
            SET Downloaded=?, DownLoadedAs=?,DownLoadedWhen=?,DownLoadedSizeKB=?
            WHERE DocNumberSequence=?;
        END TRANSACTION my_trans;
    """)
```

Would either of these solutions work for you?

Comment: Well for the second option i get this error:(<class 'pyodbc.ProgrammingError'>, ProgrammingError('42000', "[42000] [Microsof
t][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TRANSAC
TION'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL S
erver]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)"), <traceback object at 0x00000
000027817C8>)

Comment: And for the first one i get this:((<<class 'pyodbc.ProgrammingError'>class 'pyodbc.ProgrammingError'>, , PProgram
mingError('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incor
rect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table express
ion, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous s
tatement must be terminated with a semicolon. (319) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [M
icrosoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared.

Comment: Ok well you preety much had the best answer. The first one just needs to be changed to this:        update = ("""UPDATE DocumentList WITH (ROWLOCK)
            SET Downloaded=?, DownLoadedAs=?,DownLoadedWhen=?,DownLoadedSizeKB=?
            WHERE DocNumberSequence=? """) However, i used UPDLOCK instead and it seems to run faster. Still not nearly as fast as i like but i am not getting that error anymore and it is sustainable. Thank you! Also i turned autocommit=True

Comment: Ah, good catch, sorry about that! I was doing about three things at once, and just got the syntax backward.